# Como fazer o cabeçalho da tabela repetir em todas as páginas

Tags: css, html5, css3, impressão

Estou tentando imprimir utilizando CSS e tenho uma tabela com thead e tfoot, estou tentando fazer com isso imprima em todas as páginas o cabeçalho da tabela, porém o resultado é o mesmo, ele mostra apenas na primeira página e nas outras não funciona.
Se eu conseguir colocar o cabeçalho e rodapé da tabela em cada página vou ter o comportamento que eu quero que é na impressão uma tabela em cada página.

Eu tentei assim

```
thead   {display: table-header-group;   }
tfoot   {display: table-footer-group;   }
```

Comment: Como você está dividindo o conteúdo em páginas? Manualmente, ou deixando o browser fazer isso por você?

Comment: deixando o browser, porque é uma tabela que estoura o tamanho da página.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O `thead` e o `tfoot` foram feitos para isso, porem alguns browser não se adaptam muito bem com isso, principalmente o [Chrome que possui um bug](https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/issues/detail?id=566). Aparentemente o bug está presente tambem no Safari e no Opera.

Creio que terá que fazer na mão ou procurar alguma solucão em javascript.

**Recurso técnico de emergência**
Percebi que se mandar gerar PDF funciona normalmente. 
Uma solução viável pode ser gerar um PDF quando o usuário quiser imprimir.
Grampeia as teclas de atalho `CTRL + P` com Javascript, e quando o usuário pressionar, você pode abrir um popup com o PDF gerado já mandando imprimir.

*Obs.: É apenas uma alternativa caso seja realmente necessário que o cabeçalho apareça repetindo quando impresso no chrome. Desta forma ficaria padrão para todos os browser, e evitaria suporte com a famosa impressora de PDF*

Extra:

[Um bom guia sobre a criação de tabelas pode ser encontrado no css-tricks](http://css-tricks.com/complete-guide-table-element/)

Comment: Eu vi agora que era um bug, vi que no firefox e incrivelmente no IE funciona

Comment: Eu mandei gerar PDF via browser no chrome e mesmo assim não funcionou.

Comment: tenta gerar o PDF usando alguma classe da linguagem que está usando. No PHP você pode utilizar o [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)